# Select range of cells based on existence of a value found in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba and I'm trying to write a script where I want to select a Range of columns based on the existence of a value in another column. So for example in the matrix below, I want to be able to select the BC range where A column is not blank, which is B1:C3

```
    A           B        C
1 12345
2 54321
3 39284
4 <blank>
5 <blank>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Reference a Range

- [`Range.End property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end)
- [`Range.EntireRow property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirerow)
- [`Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ReferenceRangeQuick()
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count) _
        .End(xlUp).Row).EntireRow.Columns("B:C")
    Debug.Print rg.Address

End Sub

Sub ReferenceRangeStudy()
    
    Const lrCol As String = "A"
    Const sCols As String = "B:C"
    Const fRow As Long = 1
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve
    
    ' Last Row
    ' Note that this will return 1 even if there is no data in the column.
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lrCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If lRow < fRow Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print "Last Row Number:               " & lRow
    
    ' Last Row Column Range
    Dim lrcrg As Range
    Set lrcrg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(fRow, lrCol), ws.Cells(lRow, lrCol))
    Debug.Print "Last Row Column Range Address: " & lrcrg.Address(0, 0)
    
    ' Source Range
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = lrcrg.EntireRow.Columns(sCols)
    Debug.Print "Source Range Address:          " & srg.Address(0, 0)

End Sub
```